# Weird UI scaling in Android Studio Flamingo 2022.2.1 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu, user-interface, dpi, ubuntu-22.04

After update to Android Studio Flamingo 2022.2.1 I got wrong scaled interface on my main monitor. On second monitor it looks normally.
It seems that there is no scale factor slider in settings of Android Studio.
Resolution of my main monitor is 2560x1440, scale factor in system is 125%. For second monitor it's 1280x1024 and 100%. Before Flamingo update these settings worked fine.
Android Studio installed from JetBrains Toolbox, if that matters.
[Wrong scaling in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHz5j.jpg)

I tried reinstall Android Studio, tried installing Giraffe beta build. The result is the same, Studio still scales interface incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Android Studio documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/troubleshoot.html#scaling_factor_settings), Studio looking for "Text Scaling Factor" and DPI Setting in your system, but if it can't do this, it may break UI scaling. You need to go to **Help** > **Edit Custom Properties**, it will open `idea.properties` file. Add `hidpi=false` line to it and restart the IDE.

Comment: Adding hidpi=false works perfect